# Not Submitted Blank Results mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, position, string

Hello there I was wondering if I could have some help solving this (maybe) easy problem.
The code below works fine and prints all submitted fields, but there are 3 other where the user submitted blank, because its not required. These I would like to print as NOT FILLED. Given my level of programming perhaps I need some help because I have tried quite a few ways and no success. thank you for your most important help.

```
<?php
  mysql_connect ("thehost","user","password") or die ('Cannot connect to MySQL: ' .   mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("database") or die ('Cannot connect to the database: ' . mysql_error());
echo '<table>';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT column FROM table WHERE field='11'") or die ('Query is invalid: ' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo'<tr><td>';
    echo '<td>'.($row['value']!="")?$row['value']:"Not Filled".'</td>';  
    echo '</td></tr>';
}       
echo '</table>';
?>
<!--HTML dom-->
<table>
<tr>
<td>result_1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> result_2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> result_3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> result_4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You could use an if statement to see if they are blank (not sure if it would be NULL or an empty string)

Comment: Dear Marshall Tigerus, I thank you for your most welcomed help, although it was not possible to display the blank entries from the database. there are 7 submitted fields and 3 are blanks, its causing the remaining submitted rows to move up and cause wrong positioning.

Comment: What about using something like NVL in your SQL statment?  http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,59732,59732

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the greatest programmer and I understand clearly your problem I'll sugest something like this : make a verification if your row or input = "" you can fill with something like NOT FILLEd.

or if != ""

(do something or nothing

else

( fill your input with "NOT FILLED")

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you sir I_DIOT for your most welcomed help. I have tried as you mentioned with no success. it still does not display the empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  mysql_connect ("thehost","user","password") or die ('Cannot connect to MySQL: ' .   mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("database") or die ('Cannot connect to the database: ' . mysql_error());
echo '<table>';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT column FROM table WHERE field='11'") or die ('Query is invalid: ' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo'<tr><td>';
    echo '<td>';
    if(!empty($row['value'])){ echo $row['value'];}
    else{ echo "Not Filled";}
    echo '</td>';  
    echo '</td></tr>';
}       
echo '</table>';
?>
<!--HTML dom-->
<table>
<tr>
<td>result_1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> result_2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> result_3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> result_4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could just change your query to something like:

Select SomeIdColumn, NVL(column, "NOT FILLED") From table where field='11'

Do that for all affected columns, and it will return Not Filled if the column value is NULL

Comment: still empty. Does the value NOT FILLED have to be in the database? or just like it is in the php?

Comment: try the updated answer.  if you only have one column, it won't return null values.  If you have two, and one has a value, but the other doesnt, it should return a record (and then NVL can do its work

Comment: I have tried the answer above , thank you, although no success. there other columns but they are required, no problem with them they all filled with results. the problem is this column which is not required. the result-data keep going to other above empty spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I believe I will not get an answer here:

```
    echo '<table>';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM afp_data_fields WHERE field_id='11' LIMIT 1") or die ('Query is invalid: ' . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo'<tr><td>';
    echo '<td style="width: 155px;max-width: 140px; white-space: nowrap;overflow:hidden;">';
    if(!empty($row['value'])){ echo $row['value'];}
    else { echo "Not Filled";}
    echo '</td>';  
    echo '</td></tr>';
}       
echo '</table>';
```